# What does ". =" mean in GAS

Tags: assembly, syntax, gnu, symbols, gnu-assembler

I'm examining the GNU GRUB source code and in `/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/*.S` files, there are a lot of `.=` markers. Here is one from `/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S` file (line 409-414):

```
    /*
     *  Windows NT breaks compatibility by embedding a magic
     *  number here.
     */

    . = _start + GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_WINDOWS_NT_MAGIC
```

What I want to know is what the `.=` means.

Comment: Check here - http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/as.html#SEC44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAS, and perhaps in other assemblers as well, the special symbol `.` refers to the current address that the assembler will assemble into. A statement such as the one above controls where the bytes for the following code will get assembled.

The documentation for the `.` operator is [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html#Dot).

Comment: so like this in NASM?: times GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_WINDOWS_NT_MAGIC-($$-$) db 0

Comment: I haven't used NASM before. I'll check the `$` and `$$`, and replace this comment in a bit. :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Looks like it is the negative offset into current location. `$` is the current location, `$$` is the location of the section start. Assuming `times` simply repeats the db for the given amount, the NASM statement fills the rest of the section until the `XXX_MAGIC` constant with zeros. Quite different from the `.` operator. `.` simply changes the location of the next instruction to  the `XXX_MAGIC`, leaving the interim bytes uninitialized.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. Both statements achieve the same end result: the next instruction goes to the offset `GRUB_BOOT_MACHINE_WINDOWS_NT_MAGIC`. The difference is in what happens to the bytes in between - which you don't care about in the first place. :)

Comment: so it is like MASM's org where you can jump around and overwrite existing code?